# Can't start a Windows Service after installation

Tags: windows, hardware, service

So I installed a brand new service that helps hardware (like a barcode scanner) send data it receives into a Microsoft SQL database. Normally I am able to install this hardware service with little to no issues, but today I cam across something I don't think I've seen before (pretty new to the System Administration game so this could be due to my lack of experience). As far as I can tell the hardware service installs fine, but when I try to start it I get the usual cryptic Microsoft error returned to me. It says basically that windows can't start the following service on the local computer and then it says Error 13876: Load Failure. When I check the event log I see where the service fails to load up and it give me an event ID of 7023 - I go to the Microsoft Technet page to take a look at event ID 7023 and it also doesn't have a lot of info - it does have quite a few instances of this happening but no direct cause and effect. It does suggest that I go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681384.aspx to and search the error number their (13876) but all I come up with there is this:

```
ERROR_IPSEC_IKE_LOAD_FAILED

13876 (0x3634)

Load failed.
```

Does anyone have any idea what this error or Event ID 7023 actually means and if so can they point me in the right direction to solving this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the TechNet post https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733289(v=ws.10).aspx ?